# How can I use the string from other method?

Tags: java

```
package lab07_PrinceRalambomanarivo;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ESPGame {
    private String chosenColor;

public Color chooseColor(int input)
{
    Color color;

    switch(input)
    {
        case 1:
            color = Color.BLUE;
            chosenColor = "blue";
        break;
        case 2:
            color = Color.YELLOW;
            chosenColor = "yellow";
        break;
        case 3:
            color = Color.RED;
            chosenColor = "red";
        break;
        case 4:
            color = Color.GREEN;
            chosenColor = "green";
        break;
        case 5:
            color = Color.ORANGE;
            chosenColor = "orange";
        break;
        case 6:
            color = Color.CYAN;
            chosenColor = "cyan";
        break;
        default:
            color = Color.BLACK;
            chosenColor = "black";
        break;
    }
    return color;
}
public void showColor(Color color)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Guess this color");
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setLocation(300,300);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(color);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void guessColor()
{}}
```

How can I get the value of the chosenColor inside the method chooseColor() inside the method guessColor().

Comment: Programming question are not within scope here at SuperUser

Comment: Stackoverflow is the place to be.

Answer (score 2):

`chosenColor` is an instance variable so you can simply access it inside `guessColor()` i.e.

```
public void guessColor(){
    System.out.println(chosenColor);
}
```

Comment: *instance variable

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, `chosenColor` appears to be a class level private variable and hence any method in that class can use it.

Actually you are updating instance variable `chosenColor` from `chooseColor()` method . So it is not a variable from another method.